# JAXB avoid generation of duplicate classes from XSD

Tags: binding, xsd, jaxb, wsdl

I have a xsd with a element named as toc twice in the xsd. It causes error in java classes generation. Now, I want to write xml binding to resolve this issue.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../DMS_Dokument.Versenden_response.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:element[@name='toc']">
        <jaxb:factoryMethod name="TOC"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Error I get is
**Cause: unable to parse the schema. Error messages should have been provided**

Answer (score 0):

To avoid JAXB generation of duplicate classes from an XSD, you can define distinct names for the generated classes using either a local or external binding.

```
<jaxb:bindings node="XPATH">
    <jaxb:class name="YourDistinctName"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

One cause of Java class name duplication is the use of *toplevel* scoping in the global bindings.

> **Note:** The *localScoping* attribute can have the value of either `nested` or `toplevel`. This attribute describes the JAXB binding of nested XML schema component to either a nested schema-derived JAXB class or a toplevel schema-derived JAXB class. To avoid naming collisions between nested components, the default value for this attribute is nested. A developer can customize *localScoping* to *toplevel* when schema components nest too deeply or an application would prefer to not work with nested classes or when using JPA (JPA section 2.1, entities must be top-level classes).

For example, download this demo ([zip](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/releases/download/2.1.1/hisrc-basicjaxb-sample-trilogy-2.1.1-mvn-src.zip)) and consider its XML schema [trilogy.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/main/resources/trilogy.xsd) that models a `Trilogy` of books. It defines a TOC on the root `trilogy` element and another TOC for each `book`. The schema defines each TOC as an anonymous type and each TOC serves a different purpose. The first TOC describes the three book titles but the second TOC is a list of chapters in each book. Both have the same element name `<toc>...</toc>`, as shown in this XML instance, [trilogy.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/test/samples/trilogy.xml), but need distinct Java class definitions.

When the schema is customized to use `<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping=”toplevel”/>`, then JAXB attempts to generate the two types based on the one element name which leads to a name conflict.

To resolve the Java class name duplication, the demo uses a tool from the [HiSrc BasicJAXB](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) project to scan the XSD and output these suggested bindings: [trilogy.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/main/resources/trilogy.xjb). For instance, here's the binding for the book TOC:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='trilogy']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='book']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='toc']/xs:complexType">
    <jaxb:class name="TrilogyBookTocType"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The binding selects the target node using an XPATH and declares the Java class name to be `TrilogyBookTocType`.

The demo provides a bash script to run the tool but it can be run manually like this...

```
java -cp \
    $HOME/.m2/repository/org/patrodyne/jvnet/hisrc-basicjaxb-tools/2.1.1/hisrc-basicjaxb-tools-2.1.1.jar \
    org.jvnet.basicjaxb.util.CreateToplevelXJBindings \
    --nested src/main/resources/trilogy.xsd
```

The tool sends it output to `stdout` where you can copy/paste it to your binding file or schema.

##### Execution

The demo is a stand-alone Maven project. You can run the test using:

```
mvn -Ptest clean test
mvn -Pexec compile exec:java
```

###### Approach

The [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) is configured to generate **JAXB** classes using the provided [trilogy.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/main/resources/trilogy.xsd) schema and binding file [trilogy.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/main/resources/trilogy.xjb). The schema provides the namespace `"http://org.example/trilogy"` which **JAXB** uses to create the Java `package` name using its own naming convention.

As an option, a more advanced implementation of Java's built-in `Object` methods are generated using these **XJC** [hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme). In particular, the sample project uses the `toString` plugin to display *human-readable* representations of the unmarshaled `Trilogy` objects.

**hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins**

```
<args>
    <arg>-no-header</arg>
    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
</args>
```

> *Note:* When the **XJC** [hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) are used, the [hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.patrodyne.jvnet/hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime) dependency is required on the run-time class path.

###### Testing

The JUnit test class, [TrilogyTest.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/test/java/org/example/trilogy/TrilogyTest.java), scans for the sample files and invokes the method `checkSample(File sample)` to provide each file to the tester. For this project, a `JAXBContext` is created and each file in the [samples](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/test/samples/trilogy.xml) path is *unmarshaled* to a `Trilogy` object. When successful, each object is *marshaled* for logging and your [review](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/OUTPUT.txt).

###### Demonstration

A Java standard engine application with a `main(...)` method is at [`org.example.trilogy.Main`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb/blob/master/higher/assembly/samples/trilogy/src/main/java/org/example/trilogy/Main.java). This application is executed using:

```
mvn -Pexec compile exec:java -Dexec.args="src/test/samples/trilogy.xml"
```

*Disclaimer:* I am the maintainer of these [HiSrc](https://github.com/patrodyne?tab=repositories&q=hisrc) projects.